# Django send request to API, where URL is Dynamic

Tags: django, url, dynamic, python-3.6, django-urls

How the URL looks like

```
 http://<IP_ADDR>:<PORT>/api/post/<POST_NUMBER>
```

Here the POST_NUMBER is dynamic, how to send a request to the Page like this
http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/post/14
Where 14 is the post number
Here is my URL Pattern

```
path('api/post/<int>', views.PostView, name="Post")
```

Here is the PostView

```
def PostView(request,POST_NUMBER = 0):
       print(POST_NUMBER)
```

My error is PostView() got an unexpected keyword 'int'

Comment: You can try to write id instead of POST_NUMBER = 0. And then of course print the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

in urls

```
path('api/post/<post_number>', views.PostView, name="Post") 
or 
path('api/post/<int:post_number>', views.PostView, name="Post")
```

in views

```
def PostView(request,post_number = 0):
       print(post_number)
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#example)